# How to reply this mail from potential PhD professor?

Tags: phd, email

I have mailed to a professor and got the following reply in half an hour:

> Thank you very much for your interest in the position and your application. We will start evaluating applications today and will let you know the result of the first step of the evaluation process in due course.

Do I need to reply to this mail, if yes then what could be decent reply?

Comment: I would say that this email would require no response. If you haven't heard anything in two or three weeks, then you should send an email inquiring about the progress of your application.

Comment: I agree with others that no response is required. I consider this email to be a simple receipt for your application. However, if you're nervous about it, a simple thank you note would suffice.

Comment: @lsr729 - it might help to clarify whether the mail you received was an appropriate response to your message. For example, if you wrote "would you like to buy a hamburger?" and got the quoted response, that would be a different situation than if you wrote "did you receive my application?"

Comment: I feel like more and more questions on Academia.SE boil down to "how do I interact with other people?". I think the mail clearly states what is going on and this might fit better for Workplace.SE.

Comment: I don't think it is a hand written email. It is probably automatic reply. Nothing expected they just want you to know that you managed to reach them.

Comment: @Ian Please don't pollute the Workplace.SE. The answer to this question boils down to a simple "No" which is too short for a comment or answer on this site and that one. OP does not specify a goal with replying to the email so it's pure conjecture as far as what qualifies as "decent". If OP would add a little more context and a goal statement then this question might be suited for https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/ which people tend to forget about since it is sadly no longer allowed in the HNQ.

Comment: What was it a reply to?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I doubt that any reply is expected. It seems to be a general response and may not have actually come from the professor, but from his/her office, instead.

I wouldn't expect much of any response until the deadline for application has passed. I suspect that viable candidates will then get further information about what else might be needed.

But if you haven't completed your application by submitting required materials, it would probably be good to do that soon.

Comment: The email can even be interpreted as a polite request not to reply or send more inquiry emails.

Answer (score 35):

### Do not reply

That email can be categorized as a non-actionable notification email.

If you respond then you might paint yourself as a desperate, rude, or oblivious person.

- Desperate: You seek unnecessary affirmation
- Rude: You do not trust the "due course" which they mentioned
- Oblivious: You fail to understand that they are busy and would rather not receive inane follow-up emails

If you do not have a specific goal in your reply such as including crucial information which your application lacked then it's simply unneeded.

Answer (score 0):

The letter clearly states "don't call us, we'll call you".

Comment: It doesn't though - that's your sub-textual reading of it.